# OpenCV 2.4.2 findContours(), how to get only the straight lines contours

Tags: c++, visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

When I use from OpenCV 2.4.2 :

```
cv::findContours()
```

This is the output :

[image]

How can I get rid of all these irregular shapes and leave only straight lines ?

Comment: You should post some code to help us understand the problem.

Comment: A very good question, and a common problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case you can use cvMinAreaRect2. this function gives you a CvBox2D, since the contour you want has the biggest Bounding box the larger box is your goal.
also this function can help you to find contours around long lines.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`HoughLines`](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) instead of `findContours`.

Comment: Went back through my code and you are correct, I didn't do contours first. Somewhere in my memory it seems like one of them needed contours first, but I couldn't find it quickly.